# I got "unknown database" when creating a new connection in Workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql, database, schema, workbench

I am using Workbench 6.3 in Windows 8 and I want to create a new connection using a default schema that I have created. The schema's name is "mydeptosdb" and it is on Models. When I create the new connection it gives me the error:

> unknown database 'mydeptosdb'

Here is a screenshot:

http://gyazo.com/1b52aec69a238e78074cd112f4bd459b

Answer (score 0):

At final, I export the model that I had created in SQL. I left blank in "default schema" and access to it, then I put the SQL Code in a new Query and run it, it created me all that I had in the schema created in the model.

The only thing I don't understand is why creating a new model if you cant import to a new connection easily?